# Unexpected token 'export' when I'm trying to use vis.js with Svelte

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

I'm trying to create a Svelte app that will be displaying some network graphs. I'm using the vis.js package but I keep running into trouble. I also tried it in a Next.js app and it didn't work too. I get the following error when trying to run this code:

```
Unexpected token 'export'
/home/walenty/Code/diagram/my-app/node_modules/vis-data/peer/index.js:1
export * from "./esm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:170:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
```

The code:

```
// +page.svelte
<svelte:head>
    <title>About</title>
    <meta name="description" content="About this app" />
</svelte:head>

<script>
    
import { DataSet } from "vis-data/peer";
import { Network } from "vis-network/peer";
import "vis-network/styles/vis-network.css";
</script>

<div class="text-column">

</div>
```

```
// +page.ts
import { dev } from '$app/environment';

// we don't need any JS on this page, though we'll load
// it in dev so that we get hot module replacement
export const csr = dev;

// since there's no dynamic data here, we can prerender
// it so that it gets served as a static asset in production
export const prerender = false;
```

I can look into the `vis` package in `node_modules` and I can indeed see that the files finish with ESM export. But why is that an issue?

Comment: So it seems everything works fine in React.js and there are no errors using the same imports. What is the reason?

Comment: So it seems that React app is sent to the browser without any kind of server-side optimization and Next.js or Svelete apps are at least statically optimized with Node.js (I assume) and ESM exports are not available in Node.js. Is there a way of completely turning that off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding so far is that a React.js app is served directly to the browser and is not interacted with on the server side at all while Svelte or Next.js apps are compiled/optimized on the server side which causes the error, because the server side doesn't know how to parse the front-end code.

A client side library can be imported in Next.js with

```
const vis = import('vis.js').then(vis => { ... })
```

This can be put anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

It only works correctly if you are generating a SPA, make sure you have these three options correctly in the routes/+layout.js file.

```
    // if you want to generate a static html file
    // for your page.
    export const prerender = true;

    // if you want to Generate a SPA
    // you have to set ssr to false.

    export const ssr = false;  // this must be false for vis.js

    // the URL for about page witll be /about with 'ignore' (default)
    // the URL for about page witll be /about/ with 'always'
    // https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash
    export const trailingSlash = 'always';
```

https://dev.to/robertobutti/how-to-start-building-your-static-website-with-svelte-and-tailwindcss-hbk